# Angular material adds extra space using add_outline button with flex layout

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, google-material-icons

Looks like an error in a library **"@angular/material"**

Or in CDN source

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

I am trying to arrange divs inside **mat-toolbar**, but when using inside icon tag an icon add_outline, I have an extra margin.
Only the icon with name "add_outline". For example, in another screenshot is "menu", and no bugs..

[image]
[image]

```
<mat-toolbar-row style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">

    <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" onclick="this.blur()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>


        <span class="toolbar-title">{{title}}</span>


        <button mat-icon-button (click)="changeTitleButton('New')">
        <mat-icon>add_outline</mat-icon>
        </button>

    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

**Current version:
  "@angular/material": "8.0.0"**

But the same things with "@angular/material": "7.2.5"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a brilliant observation. I was able to experience the same thing... the reason is exactly the `add_outline` icon. which we can see after applying the class `::ng-deep .mat-icon{border:1px solid red; display: inherit !important; }`

But this is a peculiar one, which we can resolve via overflow property on our parent div (which houses the `mat-toolbar`)... in my case, added following to **CSS** file:

```
 .parentDiv{overflow-x:hidden;}
```

working [stackblitz available here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9ycbg)

Comment: thanks for an answer. I solved it with changing just to <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>